# How to Animate the Background of a Page

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've seen in some apps where the background, which is a static image, is animated to scroll constantly in a single direction. I've looked but haven't found any resources that would aid me in implementing this sort of feature. I have no problem setting the page background, but my issue is when trying to get the image to continuously scroll, say to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Just make one more Grid inside the Root container of the page at the same level as that of your content Grid.

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="GrdBackground" Grid.Row="0" >
      // Set this grid background as Image and animate it with animation behavior repeat.
    </Grid>

    <Grid Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
        // do all your UI in this grid.
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So now make your UI in ContentGrid and for background animation use GrdBackground. And also there is property called RepeatBehaviour for the Storyboard you can set that to repeat. And it will work.